# Problem implementing notification using firebase in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase

I am trying to implement push notification on my app using firebase. I am getting the data from firebase messaging delegate but it is not shown in the notification center.

I have configured everything from firebase to messaging delegate.

```
   func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound]) { (granted, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        else {

            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert,.sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the newer UNUserNotifications, you would need to implement this [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter) correctly and also provide the delegate to UserNotifications framework.

If you do not implement this delegate and your app ia in foreground then the default behaviour is a silent notification. Meaning you won't get ny visual notification but you will get the notification data in that method. If you are in background, your notification will show up properly regardless of whether you have implemented that method or not.

Comment: I have used the following  two methods from:
```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        NSLog("[UserNotificationCenter] applicationState:  willPresentNotification: \(userInfo)")
        //TODO: Handle foreground notification
        completionHandler([.alert])
    }
```

Comment: func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        NSLog("[UserNotificationCenter] applicationState: didReceiveResponse: \(userInfo)")
        //TODO: Handle background notification
        completionHandler()
    }

Comment: THese methods are not getting called when any data is received from firebase.

Comment: I am getting data in 
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    
        
    }

Comment: are you using firebase swizzling appdelegate?

Comment: I have no idea of swizzling appdelgate

Comment: I would urge you to read the document I have linked in my answer. See the section about completion handler. If your app is in foreground and if you do not return anything from that method, your notification will be silenced. Check if you are getting notification when app is in background. Also check you have created APNS key/ssl certificate and uploaded the same on FCM.

Comment: I have uploaded the certificate to FCM. I am not getting  notification even when the app is in background.

Comment: Can you please post your app delegate in question?

Comment: AppDelegate file is very big. That long character is not accepted here. Where should I share appdelegate?

Comment: Is there any other place where I can share app delegate with you?

Comment: difficult to debug it that way. i feel you should try to get notifications work in a new app and then integrate firebase using the docs

Comment: Okay. I will do that . Thanks a lot for your kind support. It means a lot to me.